# Transformers get named entity prediction for words instead of tokens

Tags: nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

This is very basic question, but I spend hours struggling to find the answer. I built NER using Hugginface transformers.

Say I have input sentence

```py
input = "Damien Hirst oil in canvas"
```

I tokenize it to get

```py
tokenizer = transformers.BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
tokenized = tokenizer.encode(input) #[101, 12587, 7632, 12096, 3514, 1999, 10683, 102]
```

Feed tokenized sentence to the model to get predicted tags for the tokens

```py
['B-ARTIST' 'B-ARTIST' 'I-ARTIST' 'I-ARTIST' 'B-MEDIUM' 'I-MEDIUM'
 'I-MEDIUM' 'B-ARTIST']
```

`prediction` comes as output from the model. It assigns tags to different tokens.

How can I recombine this data to obtain tags for words instead of tokens? So I would know that

```
"Damien Hirst" = ARTIST
"Oil in canvas" = MEDIUM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions here.

#### Annotating Token Classification

A common sequential tagging, especially in Named Entity Recognition, follows the scheme that a sequence to tokens with tag `X` at the beginning gets `B-X` and on reset of the labels it gets `I-X`.
The problem is that most annotated datasets are tokenized with space! For example:

```
[CSL]  O
Damien  B-ARTIST
Hirst  I-ARTIST
oil  B-MEDIUM
in  I-MEDIUM
canvas  I-MEDIUM
[SEP]  O
```

where `O` indicates that it is not a named-entity, `B-ARTIST` is the beginning of the sequence of tokens labelled as `ARTIST` and `I-ARTIST` is inside the sequence - similar pattern for `MEDIUM`.

At the moment I posted this answer, there is an example of NER in huggingface documentation here:
https://huggingface.co/transformers/usage.html#named-entity-recognition

The example doesn't exactly answer the question here, but it can add some clarification. The similar style of named entity labels in that example could be as follows:

```
label_list = [
    "O", # not a named entity
    "B-ARTIST", # beginning of an artist name
    "I-ARTIST", # an artist name
    "B-MEDIUM", # beginning of a medium name
    "I-MEDIUM", # a medium name
]
```

#### Adapt Tokenizations

With all that said about annotation schema, BERT and several other models have different tokenization model. So, we have to adapt these two tokenizations.
In this case with `bert-base-uncased`, the expected outcome is like this:

```
damien  B-ARTIST
hi  I-ARTIST
##rst  I-ARTIST
oil  B-MEDIUM
in  I-MEDIUM
canvas  I-MEDIUM
```

In order to get this done, you can go through each token in original annotation, then tokenize it and add its label again:

```
tokens_old = ['Damien', 'Hirst', 'oil', 'in', 'canvas']
labels_old = ["B-ARTIST", "I-ARTIST", "B-MEDIUM", "I-MEDIUM", "I-MEDIUM"]
label2id = {label: idx for idx, label in enumerate(label_list)}

tokens, labels = zip(*[
   (token, label)
   for token_old, label in zip(tokens_old, labels_old)
   for token in tokenizer.tokenize(token_old)
])
```

When you add `[CLS]` and `[SEP]` in the `tokens`, their labels `"O"` must be added to `labels`.

With the code above, it is possible to get into a situation that a beginning tag like `B-ARTIST` get repeated when the beginning word splits into pieces. According to the description in huggingface documentation, you can encode these labels with `-100` to be ignored:
https://huggingface.co/transformers/custom_datasets.html#token-classification-with-w-nut-emerging-entities

Something like this should work:

```
tokens, labels = zip(*[
   (token, label2id[label] if (label[:2] != "B-" or i == 0) else -100)
   for token_old, label in zip(tokens_old, labels_old)
   for i, token in enumerate(tokenizer.tokenize(token_old))
])
```